# Remove the data from app at particular date/time

Tags: java, oracle, ipad

I have an iPad app which gives users to post their offers with particular start date/time and end date/time. The offers is stored on the server through Java acting as middleware. The requirement is the other users shouldn't be able to see that offer after crossing the end date/time.

So I have to remove the offer from server or to set some flag in database.

I am thinking on ways I can achieve this?  Is polling a good option or are there any better ways to handle this scenario.

Comment: Any reason you simply can't have a view (or even just a where clause) to say `where (offer_expiry >= now())` type of thing? Polling for such a thing would be pointless. if you need data to be hidden on a schedule, then use a server-side scheduling tool to do it for you. Don't depent on client-side actions to do server-side work

Comment: More info would be nice, but if your ipod/iphone app is using a middleware service for its data, wouldn't this be handled in that middleware?  When user refreshes data, middleware won't return data that doesn't meet your date criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Why remove the offer from the database (server) thereby losing data?

Your middleware should select offers from the database where the current date is between the offers start and end dates.

The users checking for offers will only see those that are current and will by definition not then be able to see those that have expired (or not yet become active).

That way you still retain the offers in the database for any auditing you may need to perform.

An alternative method would be to move the selection logic to the database (as suggested in the comments) by using a view which only selects current offers.

If you want users to be able to see all of the offers they own then this can also be added to either the selection criteria.

As a rule of thumb, I'd be much happier keeping all the records and then filtering them rather than removing spent offers as soon as their active period is over.

If you are worried about data volumes building up then you can archive offers after a set retention period to another table (or CD or even just remove them if you REALLY need to).

Hope it helps...